# Shall we create a new npm-semver tag (or to use the loosely related semver tag)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59746824/5532169) about semver range syntax which was initially tagged with [semver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semver). As someone has pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59746824/#comment105704343_59746824), the semantic-versioning specs - [semver.org](https://semver.org/), does not include any range syntax. The range syntax is npm (and npm-like tool, e.g. yarn) specific, governed by [npm/semver](https://npmjs.com/package/semver).

Now, I totally agree with the sentiment that range syntax is not stictly-speaking semver. However, I have the feeling that, without a more specific tag, questions like mine are hard to categorize - should I tag it [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm)? what about [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg), they follow the same range syntax too. And the question is hardly anything about the package-managers themselves, but the range syntax they follow.

I would like to propose that a new tag [npm-semver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-semver) be created dedicated to this (npm-like range behavior). But given the already low volume of questions tagged with semver, it could also be argued that the new tag is not likely to be useful, and maybe using semver tag in it's loosely-related sense is more appropriate. Would like to hear your opinions.

Comment: Using two tags, npm and semver, would make the most sense to me.

Comment: Most of the time, the issues are NPM or some other tool specific, not actually SemVer related.  When you tag a post with [c], you don't also tag it with [if] simply because the source code uses `if` statements.  Similarly, the presence of a SemVer string in a "how to specify a range in NPM?" type of question, does not always warrant a SemVer tag, unless there is a question regarding SemVer precedence.

Comment: @curiousdannii That is what I did, but it seems like someone disagrees. That's why I asked.

Comment: @jwdonahue It is not simply "the presence of a semver string", most tools in the Node.js ecosystem (at least most tools I know) follows the semver range syntax defined by npm. That makes the question a semver-range question instead of a npm- question or yarn- or lerna- question. Again, I agree this is different from the actual semver specs, but it is general enough to not be called tool specific imho. To use your example, if the the post concerns only behavior of `if` statements in C, and `if` can mean different things in different language, would you not tag it with [c][if]?

Comment: I understand downvotes mean disagree in meta, but what do downvotes mean in a A-or-B question? Neither? Or what?

Comment: The SemVer spec does not specify any range notation.  Any discussion of version ranges that does not involve a question of precedence, as defined by the spec, should be considered out of scope for the Semantic-Versioning tag.

Comment: It's a matter of what expertise are you looking for?  If you want help understanding the spec, use the SemVer tag.  If you want help with a tool specific feature, like npm version ranges, then use the npm tag and don't bother the rest of us who couldn't care less how npm works.

Comment: @curiousdannii could you please post it as an answer so that people can also downvote it (to show how many agree vs disagree)?

Comment: I posted a more complete response to this, since I was the one who removed the SemVer tag from the OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where multiple tags can make sense, particularly if you are not sure which one will attract the expertise you are looking for.  This is a common state for many of us to be in, because if we had a clue, we probably wouldn't be asking the question.  When an area expert comes along and removes one or more tags, it's generally because they actually know those tags won't get you the help you need.  They are doing the entire community a favor, because, by narrowing the focus to areas that will most likely get you the help you need, they help reduce the noise here at Stack Overflow.

There are a lot of questions that do not get adequate answers here, in part because the people who could answer them, are busy following tags to questions, that turn out to have as many tags as there are pellets in a round of buck-shot.  The [thread referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59746824/5532169) does not actually exhibit the buck-shot problem. The OP applied good reasoning to the application of the tags, based on their knowledge of the problem.  I think I have proven expertise on the topic of SemVer, and believe that the tag does not in fact apply to questions regarding version range specifications.

Nearly every tool that supports SemVer, even those that promote it, has their own range specification scheme.  I personally helped create a tool that is used internally at Microsoft by tens of thousands of developers, which uses set notation for this purpose.  Npm and others have their own schemes that fit into their specific solution (if any) for managing dependencies.  The dependency graph and range specification issues are not covered by the [SemVer spec](https://semver.org/).

I am sure there will be many who fall on both sides of the dis/agree line on this in general, and perhaps even regarding the OP's specific instance.  That's just the nature of this environment.  Ultimately, those of us who devote substantial fractions of our free time trying to help others find answers, get the final say on these kinds of decisions.  So I'll just let my track record at https://github.com/semver/semver/issues and here at Stack Overflow speak for itself and move on.